# Is there a way to read WhatsApp message.db files on a PC?

Tags: whatsapp

I have a WhatsApp backup database message.db file from a Nokia Lumia phone. How can I access its contents through a PC? Or if that's not possible, what other files do I need to get from the WhatsApp folder?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be used for hacking

Comment: @NK no, this question does not help hacking because messages can be decrypted anyway if we put the WhatsApp data folder on a smartphone, messages are automatically decrypted.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a tool that can open WhatsApp backups made with Android. I assume the Windows Phone Backups are created the same way so give it a shot.

[Whatsapp Xtract: Backup Messages Extractor](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1583021)

Comment: They are not the same.

Comment: is it still working ?

Comment: probably not, as Max mentioned Android & Windows Phone WhatsApp backup files are unfortunately not the same.